# what is a good book or reference for configure / makefile scripting, in the context of iOS development?

Tags: ios, scripting, build, makefile, configure

My C and Objective-C skills are ok but i really could do with a better grasp on building binary's and libraries using configure and make files. Is there a book or consolidated reference I should be aiming to look at. Ive googled but given the generic nature of the search terms and plethora of related information i would be grateful if someone could point me at a recommended source

Comment: Why is xcodebuild not doing what you aim for?

Comment: I'm talking about building libraries from source for arm etc and how to handle all the complexities of make and autoconf etc

Comment: Sorry,  I do not have a good reference for you. Just one note; do not use GPLed code when distributing via iTunes. I am hinting this because a vast amount of libs using autoconf are in fact covered by the GPL.

Answer (score 1):

The [autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html) is the authoritative source of information on writing configure scripts, and includes sections on portable 'make' and shell programming.  As well as being a reference, it also contains a *reasonable* tutorial.

If you want to build libraries as well, then you want to look at [libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/), but unfortunately libtool can be a bit of a beast to work with unless you're also using [automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/), so this is turning into a rather long reading list.

O'Reilly have a book called 'Autotools'.  I don't know it, but given my experience with other O'Reilly books, that's the first I'd take off the shelf and browse through.